# Get result by week

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need you for order a query by the date and then if it's possible to simplify it :-)

This query will return the number of entries per week from the current day.

Here is the query :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(50), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -7), 103) as periode_join, COUNT(u.usr_ID) as cptu 
FROM [USR_USER] u 
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
WHERE u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -7) and u.[USR_JOINED_DT] <=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(50), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -14), 103) as periode_join, COUNT(u.usr_ID) as cptu 
FROM [USR_USER] u 
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
WHERE u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -14) and u.[USR_JOINED_DT] <=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -7)   

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(50), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -21), 103) as periode_join, COUNT(u.usr_ID) as cptu 
FROM [USR_USER] u 
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
WHERE u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -21) and u.[USR_JOINED_DT] <=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -14)

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(50), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -28), 103) as periode_join, COUNT(u.usr_ID) as cptu 
FROM [USR_USER] u 
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
WHERE u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -28) and u.[USR_JOINED_DT] <=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -21)   

 UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(50), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -35), 103) as periode_join, COUNT(u.usr_ID) as cptu  
FROM [USR_USER] u 
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
WHERE u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -35) and u.[USR_JOINED_DT] <=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -28)   

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(50), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -42), 103) as periode_join, COUNT(u.usr_ID) as cptu 
FROM [USR_USER] u 
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
WHERE u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -42) and u.[USR_JOINED_DT] <=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -35)
ORDER BY periode_join desc
```

Here is the result :

```
periode_join    cptu
28/05/2013  8740
25/06/2013  9773
18/06/2013  8212
11/06/2013  6644
04/06/2013  9420
02/07/2013  7868
```

Thanks a lot :-D

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

if you have SQL Server 2005 and above, you can try something like this:

```
;with CTE_Data as
(
  select
        u.usr_id,
        cast(dateadd(dd, -(datediff(dd, u.usr_joined_dt, getdate()) / 7 + 1) * 7, getdate()) as date) as periode_join
    from usr_user as u 
        inner join usi_user_site as s on u.usr_id = s.usr_id
)
select periode_join, count(usr_id) as cptu
from CTE_Data
group by periode_join
order by periode_join asc
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8147b/1)

To split data by weeks we have to take difference in days between getdate() and date from table - `datediff(dd, u.usr_joined_dt, getdate())`, then we have to get number of whole weeks - `/ 7`, then we have to substract whole number of weeks + 1.

So, for example, if date = `'2013/06/30'` then number of days = 9, whole number of weeks = 1 and we have to substract 1 + 1 weeks so we get `'2013/06/25`' and so on

Comment: Yes it works but can you explain me this line please :
    `cast(dateadd(dd, -(datediff(dd, u.usr_joined_dt, getdate()) / 7 + 1) * 7, getdate()) as date) as periode_join`